# Word riddle about the word which wants more relevancy outside space science

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here's a riddle about an ambitious word which wants to be used more often

> In space I am already
>   The problem is the lack of space in me
>   Chant me at the confectionary
>   Chant me at the ball bearings factory
>   Or if it turns out a bit forced
>   Use me in boolean algebra

Hint time:

> The space referred to in the first line is actual space while the space in the second line refers to a 'space' splitting the word in two, forming other words. The wordplay in the following clues ignore that the word lacks this space.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a

> Galaxy

In space i am already

> There are an estimated 100 billion galaxies in the universe.

The problem is the lack of space in me

> Galaxies tend to be filled with stars and planets plus, potentially, a large amount of dark matter.

Chant me at the confectionary

> [Galaxy chocolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_(chocolate))

Chant me at the ball bearings factory

> Galaxy Bearings Ltd

Or if it turns out a bit forced 
Use me in boolean algebra

> I found [this example](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82637899.pdf) of forcing in the analysis of hyperreal numbers. A universe is constructed in a Boolean-valued model of set theory and an object called a *principal galaxy* is defined on page 288. Apparently, this is a common [usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_(disambiguation)) in non-standard analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> a torus

in space

> Van Allen belt is toroidal, so are some fuel tanks on probes

lack of space in me

> torus has a hole in the middle of it

at the confectionary

> one can find donuts, which are torus

ball bearings factory

> ring of bearing is radially flattened steel torus

forced

> a wedding can be forced, symbolised by a ring which is a torus

Boolean algebra

> a wedding is an union, union is a boolean operation

Comment: Nice take! The intended answer is more word-play'iy and only the first line relates to the words real meaning.